# Android emulator freezes after loadUrl in webview several times

Tags: android, networking, webview, emulation

I'm trying to load `http://abc.com` site through the emulator and reload it automatically every X minutes. After 1-3 times loading the site by running loadUrl(`http://abc.com`) the following happens:

1. the application is not responding anymore, most of the times i do not see anymore messages in the "adb logcat" command (no GC msg as well)

2. running "adb shell" doesn't open the shell prompt, just stuck

3. sometimes i see facebook error and javascript errors (still i want to ignore them and continue work) and i don't know if they are related

4. after the problem loading any site e.g. loadUrl("http://google.com") fails

5. logcat doens't show any memory problem

6. the emulator UI still works. Opening the built in browser on google fails with page not found

It looks like the emulator network module stopped responding.
On the Android device it seems that it works but fails on the emulator. i really want it to work on the emulator.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use [WebView.reload()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#reload%28%29) instead of [WebView.loadUrl(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl%28java.lang.String%29). Perhaps the emulator just runs out of available memory while not releasing the allocated.
Alternatively you could call [WebView.freeMemory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#freeMemory%28%29) to tell the View that it should release used memory.

Comment: i'll try to call freeMemory but how will i set the URL with reload?

Comment: it will always reload the URL last set with loadURL

Comment: Did not help... note that i want to check different URL's and subsites.
In addition trying to run using android selenium and emulator is stuck as well. 
i'll be more than happy to hear new ideas... Thanks you